# Expansion of Lambert $W$ for negative values

Tags: functions, logarithms

What is a good approximation for the Lambert $W(x)$ function for values between $\frac{-1}{e}$ and $0$?  Is it simply $x-x^2$? If so, what bounds are there on the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

- R. M. Corless, G. H. Gonnet, D. E. G. Hare, D. J. Jeffrey, D. E. Knuth.  *On the Lambert W Function*, Advances in Computational Mathematics **5**(1), 1996, 329–359.  [doi:10.1007/BF02124750](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02124750) ([preprint](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf))

for pretty much everything you might want to know about the Lambert $W$ function.

In particular, you probably want formula (4.22) which expresses the principal branch of the $W$ function as
 $$
  W(z) = -1 + p - p^2/3 + (11/72)p^3 + \dots,
 $$
where $p = \sqrt{2(ez+1)}$.  Formulas (4.23) and (4.24) define the coefficients of this series.

(If you are interested in the branch taking values below $-1$, then (4.20) is a good place to start.  But your reference to $x - x^2$ implies that you are interested in the principal branch.)